# how to draw chart from json data in js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

in this code, I was able to get the data from database in the JSON format. now iam struggling to draw a chart in JS with columns as values and rows as time stamp. i have a controller(chartController) that goes into the database and extract the desired data and change it into JSON format, that is values and timestamp. then i created a route for this controller, `Route::get('json/{notification_id}','ChartController@speedHistory')->name('speedhistory')`

i hava a js class as follows,

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    $.getJSON("json", function getdata(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var pageSpeedValues = o_response;
        createChartHistory(pageSpeedLabels);
    });

    function fetchValues(Labels, Values) {

        var pageSpeedLabels = Values;
        var pageSpeedValues = Labels;

        createChartHistory(pageSpeedLabels);
    }


    // This function allows us to create a chart for the history page
    function createChartHistory(pageSpeedLabels, pageSpeedValues) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("pageSpeedHistoryChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: pageSpeedLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'PageSpeed History',
                    data: pageSpeedValues,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(32, 206, 86, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(77, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            max: 100,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }



    if(document.querySelector('#pageSpeedHistoryChart')) {
        getdata();
    }



});
```

I am not getting the data from the controller into the app.js class, any one how get the idea? iam learning js but seems a bit difficult at this point.
here is my chart controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public  function speedHistory($notification_id){

        $o_notification = Notification::find(intval($notification_id));
        $o_status = Status::where('name','speed')->first();

        $o_response = $o_notification->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get()
        ->transform(function ($item, $key) {
            return collect([
                'values' => $item->pivot->values,
                'created_at' => $item->pivot->created_at->toDateTimeString()
            ]);
        });

        return response()->json($o_response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `o_response;` in this line `var pageSpeedValues = o_response;` I dont see it getting set to anything

Comment: You call this function with one parameter `createChartHistory(pageSpeedLabels);` but it is defined with 2 parameters

Comment: Did you look at your browsers debugger console. I would expect you would see lots of error messages

Comment: @RiggsFolly . sorry i just uploaded my chart controller. o_response is values and time stamp collection. u are right lots of error, that discouraged me actually.

Comment: ___After your edit___ `$o_response` is a PHP variable.... you cannot reference it in javascript. PHP runs on the server, and javascript runs on the browser (after the PHP is long finished running)

Comment: The data returned from PHP ( if it is returned ) Is located in `data`

Comment: i think that is why i have this code in the app.js  $.getJSON("json", function getdata(data),

Comment: ___Also___ `return response()->json($o_response);` should probably be `echo response()->json($o_response);` unless there is some other PHP code that takes that returned value and echo's it back to the AJAX call

Comment: Can I suggest that you look for a simple AJAX and JSON tutorial before going back and refactoring all this code. SO **is not a tutorial site**

Comment: ok @RiggsFolly , that is i think my big problem. I really appreciate you for your time!